# How to access devices in webot robot?

Tags: motor, cameras, webots

I have trouble finding out what devices are in my robot currently I am using e-puck but I want to use a robot such as the Tesla car. I want to know what devices I can control. Example if e-puck has 2 cameras and 3 motors how will I know that. Given this information I can access them with the webot library.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply right-click on the robot in the 3D view of Webots or in the scene tree and select `Show Robot Window`. This will open a web page with the robot window including all the sensors and actuators of the robot:
[image: screenshot from Webots]

**Note**: *if the `window` field of the robot is set to something different from `<generic>`, the robot window may have a different appearance and may not display all the sensors and actuators. However, it should be easy to reset this `window` field to `<generic>`, save and reload the world to be able to display the generic robot window with all the sensors and actuators.*

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*